# iterating over non-interpolated Array of symbols python equivalent

Tags: python, ruby

I am currently writing script in python from a ruby module. I am having trouble with this aspect of the translation of ruby to python.

**Ruby:**

```
plan_metrics[test_name]={ passed_count: 0, blocked_count: 0, untested_count: 0, failed_count: 0, reviewed_count: 0, test_harness_issue_count: 0, bug_failure_count: 0, defect_list: [] }
entry['runs'].each do |run|
      metric_hash = plan_metrics[test_name]
      %i[passed_count blocked_count untested_count failed_count].each do |key|
        metric_hash[key] = metric_hash[key] + run[key.to_s]
      end
```

In this code, `entry['runs']` holds the actual values of `passed_count`, `blocked_count`, `untested_count`, and `failed_count`, but in multiple dictionaries. This is supposed to iterate over them and add up all the values and put them into ONE symbol (i.e `passed_count`) that is held in `metric_hash`

Now when i try to translate into python, i am not using symbols but instead doing it like this

**My Python translation:**

```
plan_metrics[test_name]={ "passed_count": 0, "blocked_count": 0, "untested_count": 0, "failed_count": 0, "reviewed_count": 0, "test_harness_issue_count": 0, "bug_failure_count": 0, "defect_list": [] }
for run in entry["runs"]:
       metric_hash = plan_metrics[test_name]
       for key in [metric_hash["passed_count"], metric_hash["blocked_count"], metric_hash["untested_count"], metric_hash["failed_count"]:
             metric_hash[key] = metric_hash[key] + run[str(key)]
```

But for this i am getting `KeyError: 0` on line `metric_hash[key] = metric_hash[key] + run[str(key)]`

would

`for key in [metric_hash["passed_count"], metric_hash["blocked_count"], metric_hash["untested_count"], metric_hash["failed_count"]:`

be the proper equivalent of

`%i[passed_count blocked_count untested_count failed_count].each do |key|`

and if so what is causing the KeyError: 0?

if not how can i accomplish what the ruby example did, with interating over array of symbols, in python

If you need more information on the data, letme know what to `print()` thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python you do

```
   for key in [metric_hash["passed_count"], metric_hash["blocked_count"], metric_hash["untested_count"], metric_hash["failed_count"]:
```

That means that `key` takes values from a list `[0, 0, 0, 0]`. Do you see why?

Comment: Yes that's what i have above, are you asking that i see why there is a `keyerror: 0`?

Comment: @Mfreeman: I'm asking do you see why that line is equivalent to  `for key in [0, 0, 0, 0]`?

Comment: Yeah i do see that, but i'm failing to see your point other than they are equal.  Does that mean that this wouldn't be a correct translation seeing as though the ruby example is using symbols?

Comment: In the ruby example it is changing the value of the symbols (i.e `passed_count`) but in the python example i am just changing a list of numbers not tied to anything.  My question is how would i accomplish this in python

Comment: @Mfreeman: yes, exactly, that is not a correct translation. You're not passing keys (like in ruby), you're passing values of those keys. You can fix your python code by passing keys, same as ruby. You know what `%i[passed_count blocked_count]` or `%w[passed_count blocked_count]` do in ruby, yes?

Comment: Yes, it creates an array of symbols, and in this example is used to change the value of said symbols by iterating over them.... but in python how would i accomplish this?